# Extjs:Assign value to hiiden field from store

Tags: extjs4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to assign Store value to hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515600/how-to-assign-store-value-to-hidden-field)

I have a hidden field in the form and i need to assign the value from store,but the value is not assigned to hidden field.

```
CProvider = new Ext.create('Ext.ux.form', {
{
                        xtype:'hiddenfield',  
                        name:'clearingHouseID',
                        store: loggedUser,
                        value: id
}
});
```

So how to assign a value to hidden field from store.

Comment: What is the value of 'id' in your code? Why do you need a store to assign a single value? (you'd do better with a model) If you are set on using a store, you cannot simply assign value: id, you'll need to write a function to retrieve a specific record from the store and then pull the value you want from that record before assigning it to  the 'value' or the hidden field

Comment: You should have just edited this post instead asking the same question with more data [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10515600/1062992)